# Can't edit anything in Django CMS due to cross-origin error

Tags: django, csrf, django-cms, same-origin-policy, django-csrf

About three months ago, I upgraded our old Django and CMS application to the (then) latest LTS versions (4.2.3 for Django, 3.11.3 for django-cms). After the upgrade, I got the following error when I tried to edit anything from the CMS toolbar or the CMS plugins after a successful login:

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

A short Google search later I was able to fix the issue by setting the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` in `settings.py` (depending on the environment).

This worked like a charm until a few weeks ago, when suddenly the same error appeared again. This happens on all our environments - including local - despite the fact that nothing new was deployed since the beginning of July '23.

First, I tried everything in this guide: https://noumenal.es/notes/til/django/csrf-trusted-origins/

Our staging and production django app is behind a proxy, so I verified that `HttpRequest.is_secure()` returns `True` and the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is set to `https` in the production environment. But this happens also on my local machine, where there is no HTTPS. I also verified that the CSRF cookie value and the CSRF token param in requests are, in fact, the same.

Then I tried to install the `django-cors-headers` module and set the `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`, but no luck there.

For local dev, I have these settings:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:8000']
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:8000']
```

The logs don't say anything at all about this matter.

Is there any other reason than a misconfiguration of `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` why this message suddenly shows up?

Comment: This is not an error related to CORS.

Comment: Do you have `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` in your settings?

Comment: @markwalker_ It seems that setting X_FRAME_OPTIONS to "SAMEORIGIN" does the trick! I'm just a bit confused because it worked for a month or so without this setting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version you were upgrading from, you may have missed a bit in the upgrade notes, [what's new in 3.7.2](https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.7.2.html?highlight=X_FRAME_OPTIONS#how-to-upgrade-to-3-7-2).

> Django 3.0 changed the default behaviour of the XFrameOptionsMiddleware from `SAMEORIGIN` to `DENY`. In order for django CMS to function, `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` needs to be set to `SAMEORIGIN` in the `settings.py`:
>
> ```
> X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
> ```

This option is also available on each page within the CMS, located in the advanced settings. Allowing you to override the default in your settings file.